# jQuery (Semantic-UI) ajax POST form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post, semantic-ui

I'm trying to POST a registration form using a Semantic-UI Api (based on ajax). The problem is that, I'm getting an 403 error code response. I have no idea how to handle this issue.

Code below:

@Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user/")
public class UserController {

    private final org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    // Registration

    @RequestMapping(value = "register/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public GenericResponse registerUserAccount(@Valid UserDTO user, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        LOGGER.debug("Registration of account: ", user);

        return new GenericResponse("success");
    }
}
```

UserDTO domain class:

```
@PasswordMatches
public class UserDTO {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String lastName;

    @ValidEmail
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String matchingPassword;

// ommited getters, setters etc.
}
```

.jsp (ommited unnecessary part):

```
$('.ui.form .submit.button')
        .api({
            url: '/PhotoAlbum/user/register/',
            method : 'POST',
            serializeForm: true,
            beforeSend: function(settings) {
            },
            onSuccess: function(data) {
                if(data.message == "success"){
                    window.location.href = "/PhotoAlbum/";
                }
            }
        });
```

Form :

```
<form class="ui large form">
  <div class="ui stacked segment">

    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui left icon input">
        <i class="user icon"></i>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder='<spring:message code="RegisterPage.FirstName"/>' >
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui left icon input">
        <i class="user icon"></i>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder='<spring:message code="RegisterPage.LastName"/>' >
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui left icon input">
        <i class="mail outline icon"></i>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder='<spring:message code="RegisterPage.Email"/>' >
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui left icon input">
        <i class="lock icon"></i>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder='<spring:message code="RegisterPage.Password"/>' >
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui left icon input">
        <i class="lock icon"></i>
        <input type="password" name="matchingPassword" placeholder='<spring:message code="RegisterPage.ConfirmPassword"/>' >
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui fluid large teal submit button"><spring:message code="RegisterPage.RegisterButton" /> </div>

  </div>

  <div class="ui error message"></div>

</form>
```

Apache Tomcat logs:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Nov/2015:16:11:45 +0100] "POST /PhotoAlbum/user/register/ HTTP/1.1" 403 1192
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Nov/2015:16:11:45 +0100] "GET /PhotoAlbum/user/register/?firstName=John&lastName=McMann&email=jmac%40gmail.com&password=SomePass%401&matchingPassword=SomePass%401 HTTP/1.1" 200 6577
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Any error in the spring log? Im not a guru in this area but this is probably some permission problem. Can u issue a POST without using Semantic and get a 200 back?

Comment: I had to add .csrf().disable() code inside my Security config class. Now it's works fine.